# R fill in variable for a specific observation in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some data (download link: http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AkBd6lyS3EmpdFp2OENYMUVKWnY1dkJLRXAtYnI3UVE&output=xls) that I'm trying to filter. I had reconfigured the data so that instead of one row per country, and one column per year, each row of the data frame is a country-year combination (i.e. Afghanistan, 1960, NA).

Now that I've done that, I want to create a subset of the initial data that excludes any country that has 10+ years of missing contraceptive use data.

I had thought to create a list of the unique country names in a second data frame, and then add a variable to that frame that holds the # of rows for each country that have an NA for contraceptive use (i.e. for Afghanistan it would have 46). My first thought (being most fluent in VB.net) was to use a for loop to iterate through the countries, get the NA count for that country, and then update the second data frame with that value.

In that vein I tried the following:

```
for(x in cl){
+   x$rc = nrow(subset(BCU, BCU$Country == x$Country))
+ }
```

After that failed, a little more Googling brought me to a question on here (forgot to grab the link) that suggested using `by()`. Based on that I tried:

```
by(cl, 1:nrow(cl), cl$rc <- nrow(subset(BCU, BCU$Country == cl$Country 
    & BCU$Contraceptive_Use == "NA")))
```

(`cl` is the second data frame listing the country names, and `BCU` is the initial contraceptive use data frame)

I'm fairly new to R (the problem I'm working is for an R course on Udacity), so I'll freely admit this may not be the best approach, but I'm still curious how to do this sort of aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all seem to have >= 10 years of missing data (unless I miscalculated somewhere):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat <- read.csv("contraceptive use.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE)
dat <- rename(gather(dat, year, value, -1), 
              country=`Contraceptive prevalence (% of women ages 15-49)`)

dat %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarise(missing_count=sum(is.na(value))) %>% 
  arrange(desc(missing_count)) -> missing

sum(missing$missing_count >= 10)

## [1] 213

length(unique(dat$country))

## [1] 213
```